# Why are my buttons disappearing in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I am trying to have two buttons on my React Native project and whenever I add text to my code the buttons disappear. Does anyone know why? The text I am trying to add is below

```
<Text
  style={{
    fontSize: 55,
    fontFamily: 'Futura',
    color: '#707070',
    textAlign: 'left',
    paddingTop: 50,
    paddingLeft: 30
  }}
>
  Feed
</Text>     
<Text
  style={{
    fontSize: 22,
    fontFamily: 'Futura',
    color: '#BABABA',
    textAlign: 'left',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingLeft: 30
  }}
>
  Find the Circle for your needs!
</Text>
```

and the code I am trying to add it to is this

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
    <Button title="Button 1"/>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
    <Button title="Button 2"/>
  </View>
</View>
```

All of my code is below but it only shows the text not the buttons.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class GridView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View> 
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 55,
            fontFamily: 'Futura',
            color: '#707070',
            textAlign: 'left',
            paddingTop: 50,
            paddingLeft: 30
          }}
        >
          Feed
        </Text>     

        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 22,
            fontFamily: 'Futura',
            color: '#BABABA',
            textAlign: 'left',
            paddingTop: 10,
            paddingLeft: 30
          }}
        >
         Find the Circle for your needs!
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Button title="Button 1"/>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Button title="Button 2"/>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  headers: {
    fontSize: 50,
  }
});
```

Comment: AFAIK the `Button` component doesn't render any `children`. The text you want to display is the `title` prop IIRC.

Comment: @DrewReese how would I fix this? I am new to react native and not entirely sure how to apply that

Comment: I would say it's as trivial as moving the text from the `Text` component to the `Button`'s `title` prop.... but you've also some styling that I'm assuming you want working as well. I'm standing up an Expo Snack now to test this.

Comment: This example works for me in a new project? I can see both text and buttons. Are you wanting the text in the text tags to be the title in the buttons? You can also add click events with difference wrapper components to make anything clickable.

Comment: @ColinHale are you using react Native?

Comment: Hmm, I had assumed you are trying to render the `Text` component in the button, but I see that they are outside. Can you confirm what you are really trying to render?

Comment: FWIW I can't seem to be able to reproduce the issue as you describe. Here's a running [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@drew.w.reese/quiet-almond) of your code. The text and the buttons render.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your issue: My guess is there is something wrong with a parent component that is cutting of the render. If this is the only view on page also try adding the style {flex:1} to the outer most layer. This can happen sometimes if there is some styling on navigation setup that get passed to childern.

```
<View style={{flex:1}> 
 <Text style={{...}}>Feed</Text>     
 <Text style={{...}}>Find the Circle for your needs!</Text>
 <View style={styles.container}>
 <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
  <Button title="Button 1"/>
 </View>
 <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
  <Button title="Button 2"/>
 </View>
  </View>
</View>
```